# Как при многострочном тексте в блочном элементе убрать лишнее пространство? скрин присутсвует

Tags: html, css

Подскажите плиз, текст вот не влез в блочным элемент, и перенесся на новую строку, но блочный элемент обратно не сузился и оставил лишнее пространство (красным цветом). как это лишнее пространство убрать? как сделать так, чтобы блочный элемент равнял по содержимому, ибо ширина span в моем случае определяется верно.
Такая же ситуация и с равнением текста справа (лишнее пространство слева)
ну или чем div заменить можно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не предусмотрена система переноса строк, например, как в русском языке, у Вас просто не вмещается слово "hfhfhhh" (или как-то так, не стал буквально переводить), вот оно и перенеслось на новую строку.

Comment: никак, ширина блочного элемента по умолчанию 100% от контейнера, если нужно чтобы она зависела от ширины контента, нужно сменить на `inline-block`